# Different fills for different facet_grids using geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill

I'm new with ggplot2 and I have a question that I couldn't find the answer.
I've created the following toy data to help in the explanation:

```
data <- data.frame(tech=c(rep(letters[1:15],2)), 
     sep=c(rep(c("SitutationA", "SitutationB"),each=15)), 
     error=c(runif(15,min=-0.2, max=0.5), runif(15, min=0.3, max=1)))
```

I want to plot a `geom_bar` graph showing the "error"  (axis y) for each technique "tech" (axis x) divided in two different situations (SituationA and SituationB) using `facet_grid`. The color (`fill`) of each bar should represent the "error" of each technique, and not the technique (as a factor). The errors for situations A and B are measured in different scales. However, in my code, an error of the same value have the same color in both situations. I do not want this behavior since they were measured in different scales.  Thus, I would like that the colors in Situations A and B were independents.

The following code plots the graph, but using the same color for both situations.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=tech, y=error)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=error), stat="identity", position="dodge") + 
  facet_grid(sep ~ ., scales="free_y") + 
  scale_fill_continuous(guide=FALSE)
```

How could I use different continuous fills for each facet (situationA and situationB)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two different fill scales on the same plot.

Solution to the problem could be to make two plots and then put them together with `grid.arrange()` from library `gridExtra`.

In the first plot put only values of `SitutationA`. Changed y scale to show values with two numbers after decimal point (to be the same as for second plot). Removed x axis title, texts and ticks and changed plot margins - set bottom margin to -0.4 to reduce space between plots.

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
p1<-ggplot(subset(data,sep=="SitutationA"), aes(x=tech, y=error)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=error), stat="identity", position="dodge") + 
  facet_grid(sep ~ ., scales="free_y") + 
  scale_fill_continuous(guide=FALSE)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,0.25,0.50))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,-0.4,1),"lines"))
```

For the second plot (`SitutationB`) changed top plot margin to -0.4 to reduce space between plots. Then changed `scale_fill_continuous()` and provided new colors.

```
p2<-ggplot(subset(data,sep=="SitutationB"), aes(x=tech, y=error)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=error), stat="identity", position="dodge") + 
  facet_grid(sep ~ ., scales="free_y") + 
  scale_fill_continuous(guide=FALSE,low="red",high="purple") +
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(-0.4,1,1,1),"lines"))
```

Now put both plots together.

```
grid.arrange(p1,p2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Didzis Elferts. I thought there was a trick that could solve my problem without using grid.arrange. Anyway, I haven't used  facet_grid with grid.arrange yet, and I think it looks much better than my old graph.